# CSS rule for no matching general sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

If I want to style a `div` element only when there is a `p` sibling, I can write the following CSS rule:

```
p ~ div
```

Is there a CSS rule for styling an element when there **isn't** a matching sibling?

For example something like:

```
p !~ div
```

---

```
<section>
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</section>
<section>
   <div></div> <!-- Style this one -->
   <div></div> <!-- Style this one -->
</section>
```

Comment: As you may have guessed, no such combinator exists, but that does sound interesting on paper. Not sure how it would work in practice. Selectors 4 does make it possible through allowing combinators in `:not()` though, as I mentioned in my answer, but there's also the issue of fast vs complete profiles making it unusable in CSS anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `:not()` allowed combinators, you would be able to simply do `div:not(p ~ div)`. But it doesn't, so you won't be able to use `:not()` in that manner.

The selector you need will depend on your structure. In your case, if not having the `p` causes the first `div` to be the first child of your `section`, you can use `div:first-child` to make sure you select your `div`s if and only if that condition is met:

```
div:first-child, div:first-child ~ div
```

If your structure does not allow such a selector to be constructed, then you will have to rely on an overriding rule as Danield suggests.

Comment: Thanks, your solution for detecting `div:first-child` will work in my case, as `p` is the only other element that will exist in the `section`, and will always be the first element if it is present. There is a risk that future development will break this rule however, so its a shame there's no way of incorporating `:not()` but at least its prevented having to use javascript!

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it the other way around:

Set a style for **all** the divs according to the way you want them when no `<p>` elements are there.

Then override that style when there is a `<p>` element.

```
section div
{
    color: green;
}

section p ~ div
{
    color: black;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3TYwK/2/)**

Comment: +1 Thanks, I had considered this, but I wanted don't want non-CSS3 browsers to display `green` for every element.

Comment: @Curt: `~` is exceptionally well-supported - IE7 does so with obscure bugs that probably won't occur in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just give id/class to div and write its corresponding CSS simple