# Is there a way of selecting multiple adjacent classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way of selecting multiple (i.e. "any number" of) adjacent classes?

In other words, let's say we have

```
<div class="marker">One</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="marker">Two</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="marker">Three</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="interruption"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="marker">Four</div>
```

I want to select any "marker" which follows any number of, but *only* "item" elements

like...

```
.marker + .item + .marker { display:block;}
```

It will select "Two" and "Three" above, but not "four" because it is preceded by a div with a class other than `item`.

Comment: Basically no...CSS can't detect preceding elements.

Answer (score 2):

CSS does not provide a selector representing multiple adjacent siblings at once. Each selector represents exactly one element; if you need to represent multiple siblings, you will need an equal number of adjacent sibling selectors.

There doesn't appear to be a way to represent a `.marker` whose general preceding siblings do not match a certain selector either, which may be related to CSS's inability to select sibling elements within a limited range. See these related questions:

- [How can I target a specific group of siblings in a flat hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330757/target-all-general-siblings-before-next-occurence-of-same-type)
- [CSS rule for no matching general sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660995/css-rule-for-no-matching-general-sibling)

It seems that if you're after a pure CSS solution, you'll need to know in advance up to how many `.item` elements may separate two `.marker` elements, and hardcode as many adjacent sibling selectors as necessary, as shown in [Josh Crozier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747742/is-there-a-way-of-selecting-multiple-adjacent-classes/28747769#28747769). If you don't know this in advance, you will need to resort to using JavaScript somehow.

Comment: I may be missing something, but is my answer really hardcoding adjacent sibling selectors? It should work with those 2 selectors for any amount of separating `.item` elements (I think?).

Comment: @Josh Crozier: Oh, I didn't look closely enough. I'd say you're still assuming that `.interruption` will not occur less than two `.item` elements away from the next `.marker`, which we don't know for sure. It requires knowing the structure in advance either way.

Comment: Yea, you're absolutely right. I didn't consider that.

Comment: @Josh Crozier: Unfortunately, overriding stops working once you have other `.marker` elements after the one directly following `.interruption`. As I want to account for that case I have edited my answer to remove the overriding workaround entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `.interruption` element will only consecutively occur once, then you could combine the selector `.marker + .item + .marker` with `.marker ~ .item  + .item + .marker` in order to achieve this.

If this is not the case, then you would need to override the initial CSS as [BoltClock suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28747948/2680216).

```css
.marker + .item + .marker,
.marker ~ .item  + .item + .marker {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="marker">One</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="marker">Two</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="marker">Three</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="interruption"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="marker">Four</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I clarified my question a bit... That will select some undesired divs.

Comment: No, I didn't want to select "Four"